# Laravel - Editing default exception view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, exception

Most of the people here have been asking questions about making custom exceptions and subsequent custom error messages/views for them. What I have been unable to find is to override sort of or pass params to the default exception (render) view and also editing the view a little (like addingh some js to it). Reason being is that I wanna handle all exceptions the same way but with a little mod on the view side. Is there a way to do it or I just have to copy all the view content from the laravel source and make my own custom view and render it in all cases (Also, how to show the stack trace there in case of non-productions environments) ? Thanks in advance.

PS: I'm using Laravel 5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 Error Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27889647/laravel-5-error-handling)

Comment: add a blade file with the name of the error code(ex: 404.blade.php) to views/errors

Comment: @Matius Nugroho Aryanto I don't think so, that one is showing how to render different views based on the exception type, not what I'm looking for exactly.